# ProFTPD - set a group manager to access all users files in the group tree

Tags: permissions, mysql, chroot, proftpd

I am currently developing a client application with pyqt and ftplib to help backup/restore file to/from a [ProFTPD](http://proftpd.org/) server.
The company is divided into many agencies and every agency is a ftp group with many users.
Authentication is made using MySQL backend because users and groups are created with proFTPd Administrator and users access is chrooted.

Users have roles already stored in users table.The problem now is I want to configure proftpd so every head of agency can see and download files of all users of his agency.
Any suggestion on how to achieve this and how to configure that for proftpd?

Thanks and sorry for poor english.